# is it possible to use LinearSVC model with OneVsRest in PySpark?

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark

Im trying to use LinearSVC model in OneVsRest in PySpark , but it seems its not supported yet.

My error msg

```
LinearSVC only supports binary classification. 1 classes detected in LinearSVC_43a50b0b70d60a8cbdb1__labelCol
```

What kind of changes do i need in order to implement it in PySpark?

Does anyone know when will OneVsRest in Pyspark will support LinearSVC?

Comment: You dataset has currently just one class. Is that intended?

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that your dataset contains only one class currently, but LinearSVM is a binary classification algorithm which requires exactly two classes.
I'm not sure if the rest of your code will cause any issues, because you haven't posted anything. Just in case you or someone else needs it, have a look below.

Like alrady said, LinearSVM is a binary classification algorithm which will never support multi class classification by definition but you can always reduce a multi class classification problem to a binary classification problem. [One-vs-Rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification#One-vs.-rest) is an approach for such a reduction. It trains one classifier per class and from an engineering perspective it makes sense to seperate this to a dedicated class like spark [did](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.OneVsRest). The OneVsRest trains one classifier for each of your classes and a given sample is scored against this list of classifiers. The classifier with the highstest score determines the predicted label for your sample.

Have a look at the code below for the usage of OneVsRest with LinearSVC:

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.classification import OneVsRest, LinearSVC
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

df = spark.read.csv('/tmp/iris.data', schema='sepalLength DOUBLE, sepalWidth DOUBLE, petalLength DOUBLE, petalWidth DOUBLE, class STRING')


vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["sepalLength", "sepalWidth", "petalLength", 'petalWidth'], outputCol="features")
df = vecAssembler.transform(df)

stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="class", outputCol="label")
si_model = stringIndexer.fit(df)
df = si_model.transform(df)

svm = LinearSVC()
ovr = OneVsRest(classifier=svm)
ovrModel = ovr.fit(df)

evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName="accuracy")

predictions = ovrModel.transform(df)

print("Accuracy: {}".format(evaluator.evaluate(predictions)))
```

Output:

```
Accuracy: 0.9533333333333334
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a funny bug in PySpark. If you have multiple classes, they must be identified starting from zero.

I went through this bug just right now. I had a dataframe built in the same way they suggest in the [LinearSVC guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.LinearSVC).

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    Row(label=1.0, features=Vectors.dense(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
    Row(label=0.0, features=Vectors.dense(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))]).toDF()
```

Originally, it was a plain RDD, then I transformed each RDD record in a `Row`. I had a three-classes problem where classes were named `1`, `2` and `3`. I instantiated a `OneVsRest` object (just like @cronoik suggested) and I went through the same error as yours.

So I took the `df` dataframe exactly as initalised in their user guide (see above) and I decided to start playing with it by adding and removing classes. So I simply substituted in the second pattern `label=0.0` with `label=2.0` and the error appeared. Even with their dataframe, even with just two classes.

So I changed the naming of my classes from `1`, `2`, `3` to `0`, `1`, `2` and the error went away.

Hope this helps!